# collecting logs with log4j2 v2.9

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

i have a question regarding log4j2 with version 2.9.
Basically I want to do the same as described here (log4j), only with 2.9:
[Sample log4j v1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402896/how-to-get-logger-value-in-a-string-array)

I need a logger that can be called in any method in the class. This is to collect all subsequent logs recursively from a certain starting point. The collection should be able to be read out in any form later on.

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
public void meth1(){
  StringWriter/ List/ String or whatever
  logger.add(Collector);
  logger.info("Start");
  this.meth2();
  this.meht3();
  logger.info("Stop");
  => do something with the collected logs
}
public void meht2(){
  logger.info("meth2: add Collection");
}
public void meth3(){
  logger.info("meth3: add Collection");
}
public void meht4(){
  logger.info("foo");
}
```

as soon as the end is set in a form, the following logs should be included in the collection:

- Start
- meth2: add Collection
- meth3: add Collection
- Stop

thanks for your help

Comment: did you try to port the code to log4j 2.x? Log4J 2 also has a WriterAppender: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/WriterAppender.html.

Comment: I have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603750/log4j2-write-logs-to-writer but without success

Comment: show us your code, so we can see why you had no success: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: as I said, I tried the version of Vika Sachdeva in the thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603750/log4j2-write-logs-to-writer). But there is nothing in the StringWriter at the end.

Comment: at log4j (v1) we did it this way:
Layout layout = new PatternLayout();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
WriterAppender writerAppender = new WriterAppender(layout, stringWriter);
logger.addAppender(writerAppender);

on the page (https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=143918601) under "Unit-testing" an update to v2 is also displayed, but here the appender is not used at all.....

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I came up with the following solution which works for me using Log4J 2.8. I've added some comments to the code to explain the different steps necessary.

It's important that the logger is requested with the same name (line marked with `/* 1 */` as for which the configuration is stored (line marked with `/* 2 */`. This implies, that the class name cannot be used to get the logger, or that `MyClass.class.getName()` should be used at `/*2*/`.

```
public class LoggingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define the logger, could also be static in class
        final String loggerName = "myCollectingLogger";
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(loggerName); /* 1 */

        // the log message collector
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        // start adapting the logger configuration
        LoggerContext ctx = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        // create our appender
        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n").build();
        WriterAppender writerAppender = WriterAppender.newBuilder().setName("writerAppender").setTarget(writer).setLayout(layout).build();

        // add the appender to a LoggerConfig
        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("writerAppender", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.INFO, "example", null, refs, null, config, null);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(writerAppender, null, null);

        // enable the LoggerConfig in the LoggerContext
        config.addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig); /* 2 */
        ctx.updateLoggers();

        // use the logger:
        logger.info("Start");
        logger.warn("foo bar");
        logger.error("relax, it's just a test");
        logger.info("Stop");

        System.out.println("--- the collected log messages: ---");
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I've adjusted it to my needs:

```
public static StringWriter createStringWriter(String classname){
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
            .withPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n").build();
    WriterAppender writerAppender = WriterAppender.newBuilder()
                                        .setName(classname + "writeLogger")
                                        .setTarget(stringWriter)
                                        .setLayout(layout)
                                        .build();
    writerAppender.start();
    config.addAppender(writerAppender);
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(classname);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(writerAppender, null, null);
    ctx.updateLoggers();
    return stringWriter;
}

public static void removeStringWriter(String classname){
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(classname);
    loggerConfig.removeAppender(classname + "writeLogger");
    ctx.updateLoggers();
}
```